# What happened to the thousands of Huragok on board Gettysburg at the end of Operation First Strike?

Tags: halo

I've been listening to lots of Halo audiobooks and I'm starting to get confused with my unanswered questions.

The books are in the following order

- *Cole Protocol*
- *Fall of Reach*
- *The Flood*
- *First Strike*
- *Broken Circle*
- *Ghosts of Onyx*
- *Glass Fields*
- *The Thursday War*

In *The First Strike*, Master Chief and the crew managed to board a Covenant flagship that Cortana took control over. This ship had only about a hundred Covenant soldiers, and thousands of engineers. During the events of *Operation First Strike*, where Master Chief and the Spartans blew up a Covenant space station and 500 Covenant warships, thousands of Huragok were transferred to Gettysburg from the alien ship.

*Broken Circle* was an unsatisfying book about a persecuted Sangheili keep that splintered off the home world and lived in a derelict Forerunner space station.

*Ghost of Onyx* was about the Spartan 3s.

*Glass Fields* was about the dyson sphere Forerunner world.

The next book in chronological order that deals with the UNSC is *The Thursday War*. Also this book references none of the events of *First Strike* or the results.

Which is too bad because it would be interesting to know, how the war with the Covenant was affected by the loss of most covenant navy. Also the book mentions the Huragok obtained from the dyson sphere, and the few select Huragok obtained from the galaxy in various ways. The Huragok are emphasized as a rare and precious commodity.  Which makes no sense when the Gettysburg made landfall on earth with thousands of Huragok in its bays. The UNSC Infinity, the ship that the *Thursday War* book takes place on, is the Earth's flagship that took up a massive portion of UNSC's budget. You would have thought that the Earth's flagship, which cost a big portion of all money to build, would have benefited from the thousands of Huragok roaming earth.

I was thinking *The Thursday War* must have been published before these facts were written, however it looks like *The First Strike* was written in 2003 whereas as *The Thursday War* was written in 2019.

I don't know what's up with this, maybe they made *First Strike* no longer canon or something because maybe it would be way too easy to win with thousands of Huragok and the Covenant not having ships.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This question is very difficult to read because you haven't capitalized titles, or use appropriate punctuation, for example commas between items in a list.  You should [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: "whereas as The Thursday War was written in 2019"                                                                         
   (it was first published in 2012)